# At Azure, Google Drive Api file upload fails, returns null

Tags: c#, azure, google-drive-api

I'm trying to upload an image to Google Drive using Google Drive Api. Our web site is hosted on an Azure server. Uploading works both in local PC and another physical server which is not cloud.

**insertRequest.ResponseBody** comes null after calling

`insertRequest.Upload()`.

But I couldn't get any error message. Here is the code I'm using;

```
          ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
           new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
           {
               Scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.DriveFile }
           }.FromCertificate(certificate));

        // Create the service using the client credentials.
        service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = applicationName
        });

        var uploadStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(base64));
        // Get the media upload request object.
        Google.Apis.Drive.v2.FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload insertRequest = service.Files.Insert(
            new File
            {
                Title = fileTitle,
                Parents = new List<ParentReference>() { new ParentReference() { Id = folderId } }
            },
            uploadStream,
            "image/jpeg");
        insertRequest.ProgressChanged += Upload_ProgressChanged;
        insertRequest.ResponseReceived += Upload_ResponseReceived;
        insertRequest.Upload();
        File file = insertRequest.ResponseBody;
```

Comment: You are trying to upload files from your website hosted in Azure, am i right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sorry for late answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved the problem. It was totally our mistake.

There was no folder with the given ID. Giving an ID of existing folder solved the problem.

When there is no folder with the given ID, it throws an exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". We, first, thought that it was an exception from our C# codes. But apparently, Google SDK throws it.